# Tool for cleaning up surplus nvidia installers

Tags: windows, uninstall, nvidia

Nvidia has a tendancy of leaving its clothes all over the apartment, its dirty dishes in the sink...

I mean, it tends to keep lots of old versions of installers, most of which arn't needed. I'm lazy, and want something I can run periodically to hoover up these installers automatically (or better yet, I can schedule)

I'm running windows 10, but support for most modern windows would likely be nice. Is there anything that does this?